# Social Security Spousal Benefit while Spouse is Working

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security

For US Social Security, a person of Full Retirement Age (FRA) can claim spousal benefits to receive 50% of the FRA benefits of their spouse.

Suppose person A is of FRA and has no income.  Person B (the spouse of A) has a FRA benefit value of X USD, but is 62 (younger than FRA) and still works with a high income.

When B claims benefits, the value received is at most 0.75 * X (due to their young age).  Moreover, no value is received (due to high income).

What is the spousal benefit of person A?
Is it:

1. 0.50 * X
2. 0.50 * 0.75 * X (for B claiming early)
3. 0 (due to B's income)

[This SSA link](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/retire/1943.html) suggests that Option 2 would not happen, but does not address whether it would be Option 1 or 3.